# AWS TransferListener throwing onError and onStateChanged gets called

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

Following is a code snipped from my android app,

onError gets called also onStateChanged gets called after some times,

Error that I get is

The requested range is not satisfiable (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 416

Please throw some insight if some one has experienced this kind of behaviour.

```
 observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged(int i, TransferState transferState) {
                        Log.d("AWS download state", transferState.toString());
                        if (transferState == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                            downloadCallBack.OnDownloadCompleteSuccess(filename);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(int i, long l, long l1) {

                        Log.d("progress Change", "Dummy logging");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int i, Exception e) {
                        Log.e("aws error", e.toString());

                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(gCtx, "Error! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }catch (Exception e1){
                            Log.e("error",e1.getLocalizedMessage().toString());
                        }



                    }
                });
```

Comment: Are you clean the transfer listener @on pause or anywhere

Comment: @PraveenRawat what is the relevance of that question in this context?

Comment: due to cache problem , I have implementing but its working.

Comment: @PraveenRawat My question is if onError gets called, why does onStateChanged gets called?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat What is the transferState when onStateChanged is called?

Answer (score 0):

When there is an error occurred during the upload/download task, the SDK calls onError callback with the appropriate exception object. In addition to that, the onStateChanged is called with the TransferState.FAILED. Hence you get both the callbacks.